# Web API 2 Redirection with Windows Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I've developped a Web Controller in C# that handle an HttpRequest from Internet. 
This Controller is secured by Windows Authentification.

I want that Controller to redirect the Client to another IIS also protected by Windows Authentification.

I used this instruction:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Found);
                    response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://otherwebsite");
                    return response;
```

The other website is in the same LAN that the Controller but has not the same Internet URL.
Is there a way to pass the Windows Credentials to the redirect response?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't Windows credentials kick-in once the client is redirected to the new URL?

Comment: Nope, a second prompt is showed in the browser when the Client is redirected. That's because the redirection goes to another web server.

Comment: Perhaps it's something in the IIS configuration?